# Is there a way of uploading an image using AJAX/jQuery without the use of Flash or iframes?

Tags: jquery, image, flash, iframe, upload

Also trying to avoid any use of plugins, (apart from jQuery of course, whether you would call that a plugin or not).  I have a large system already and don't really want to load it with loads of plugins.  Of course, if I need too I'll be looking for something very light weight.

Comment: Do you have to support old IE?

Comment: Well, in that case... http://www.profilepicture.co.uk/ajax-file-upload-xmlhttprequest-level-2/

Comment: You could just create a hidden iframe and have your form submit directly to that hidden iframe. No extra plugins needed.

Comment: The only problem with that is I then need to load all my styles (it's very rich in CSS) on the same page, as well as jQuery. Don't see the point in loading that all again just for a silly iframe.

Comment: That's unfortunate. The FileAPI doesn't work in Safari and one of our main users for this system all run on Macs.

Comment: @OliverTappin - Why do you have to load all your styles & JS in the `iframe`?

Comment: Due to how I would like to handle the upload/errors/completion

Comment: You could handle the errors etc. by calling a method on the parent page from within the iframe on complete or error. `<script>window.parent.uploadComplete()</script>` or `<script>window.parent.uploadFailed("something happened")</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think so. Even if some of the well known javaScript image upload plugin use iFrame under the hood.

Comment: correct..upload is natural submission phenomenon..doing it ajax means normal submission using iframe.

Comment: So in answer to my question, there is no way of doing it.  What kind of world are we living in?!

Comment: Yes, this is it. We have many way out as you mentioned flash/iFrame.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html

Comment: I think this jQuery plugin is using iFrame in its core lib.