# Is there any way of uploading image from computer using Ajax/Jquery which supports IE 9?

Tags: jquery, image

I'm trying to figure out the uploading image thing.

Works on google chrome well but not on IE 9.

Are there any tutorials where I can find uploading image from computer which works on IE9?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes there is. Use <input type="file">. :) Or improve your question..

Comment: Err.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162907/is-there-a-way-of-uploading-an-image-using-ajax-jquery-without-the-use-of-flash

Check this out. The question is far more similar but then it doesnt work with IE9. So i wanted the similar answers which works with IE 9.

Comment: Yes there are many tutorial where u can find uploading image from computer using IE9? Do you need it ?? **Man improve your question first**

Comment: Sorry bro. I meant i want to know how to upload image and display it using ajax/jquery WHICH WORKS ON IE9.

Comment: And that was too hard to specify in your question why exactly?

Comment: ok. I have a module in which i have a browse button to upload image from computer and display it on either div/iframe/canvas (whatever helps) using jquery/ajax or if necessary using jsp file too. Drag and drop doesnt work on Internet Explorer 9. so i m finding it difficult to get this. Hope you guys understood what i exactly want

Answer (score 0):

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), [Plupload](http://plupload.com/). These are jquery plugin what are you looking for.

Plupload has many features and uses than Uploadify

Answer (score 0):

You may try **[AX Ajax Multi Uploader](http://code.google.com/p/ax-jquery-multiuploader/)** and also here is their homepage http://www.albanx.com/